Why does Akira's move happen rarely in Street Fighter V?
These are the moves of Akira in Street Fighter V.
Her Critical Art, Kyoso Kiko Kai (where her brother comes out to help), can always be executed in the two-person practice mode. But in arcade mode, it often doesn't work. Very rarely, it will work once. I've tried having the "meters" filled up to 1 block, and it still won't work. What is the rule?
Likewise, it's the same for Haten No Kamae, which is really easy to invoke: Hard punch and Hard kick. In practice mode, it always happens. In arcade mode, it happens very rarely.



What's your Practice Mode's Critical and V Gauge settings? Those are Akira's Critical and V moves. https://www.ign.com/wikis/street-fighter-5/Training_Mode
